# Dialog chain issues (passing messages)

Tags: c#, botframework

I have this piece of code.

```
public class HotelBotDialog
{

    public static readonly IDialog<string> dialog = Chain.PostToChain()
        .Select(msg => msg.Text)
        .Switch(
             new RegexCase<IDialog<string>>(new Regex("^hi", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), (context, txt) =>
             {
                 return Chain.ContinueWith(new GreetingDialog(), AfterGreetingContinuation);
             }),
             new DefaultCase<string, IDialog<string>>((context, txt) =>
             {
                 return Chain.ContinueWith(FormDialog.FromForm(RoomReservation.BuildForm), AfterGreetingContinuation);                   
             }))
 .Unwrap()
 .PostToUser();

    private async static Task<IDialog<string>> AfterGreetingContinuation(IBotContext context, IAwaitable<object> res)
    {
        var token = await res;
        var name = "User";
        context.UserData.TryGetValue<string>("Name", out name);
        return Chain.Return($"Thank you for using the hotel bot: {name}");
    }
}
```

}

Which will work, except the issue is that whenever I fell into the "default case" I need to enter in a second entry in order to kick off my form.  So here is what the dialog looks like

Me: Test
Bot: 
Me: Test2
Bot: Welcome to the Hotel bot...blah blah

What I want is

Me: Test
Bot: Welcome to the Hotel bot...

I would think there is something wrong where I'm not passing over the original message or something.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FormDialog.FromForm` method has an overload that receives the FormOptions. One of the values of that enum is PrompInStart which basically will do what you want; start the form right away.

If you don't provide any value for the FormOptions, it defaults to None and then the [FormDialog](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/5cf71c742f27d89e9dbc4076f850122bd6edac11/CSharp/Library/FormFlow/FormDialog.cs) just sit there waiting for a new message.

This the logic in the BotBuilder that does that (also [linked](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/5cf71c742f27d89e9dbc4076f850122bd6edac11/CSharp/Library/FormFlow/FormDialog.cs#L260)):

```
if (this._options.HasFlag(FormOptions.PromptInStart))
{
    await MessageReceived(context, null);
}
else
{
    context.Wait(MessageReceived);
}
```

So, to resolve your issue, change the way you are instantiating the form to:

```
FormDialog.FromForm(RoomReservation.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart)
```

Notice the **FormOptions.PromptInStart** at the end.